# How to make LIKE in SQL look for specific string instead of just a wildcard

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    [content_id] AS [LinkID]
    , dbo.usp_ClearHTMLTags(CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('root/Physicians/name'))) AS [Physician Name]
FROM
    [DB].[dbo].[table1]
WHERE
    [id] = '188'
    AND
    (content LIKE '%Urology%')
    AND
    (contentS = 'A')
ORDER BY
    --[content_title]
    dbo.usp_ClearHTMLTags(CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('root/Physicians/name')))
```

The issue I am having is, if the `content` is `Neurology` or `Urology` it appears in the result.

Is there any way to make it so that if it's **Urology**, it will only give **Urology** result and if it's **Neurology**, it will only give **Neurology** result.

It can be Urology, Neurology, Internal Medicine, etc. etc... So the two above used are what is causing the issue.

The `content` is a ntext column with XML tag inside, for example:

```
<root><Location><location>Office</location>
<office>Office</office>
<Address><image><img  src="Rd.jpg?n=7513" /></image>
<Address1>1 Road</Address1>
<Address2></Address2>
<City>Qns</City>
<State>NY</State>
<zip>14404</zip>
<phone>324-324-2342</phone>
<fax></fax>
<general></general>
<from_north></from_north>
<from_south></from_south>
<from_west></from_west>
<from_east></from_east>
<from_connecticut></from_connecticut>
<public_trans></public_trans>
</Address>
</Location>
</root>
```

With the update this `content` column has the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Physicians>
        <name>Doctor #1</name>
        <picture>
            <img src="phys_lab coat_gradation2.jpg?n=7529" />
        </picture>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <langF1>
            <a href="/ult.aspx" title="English">English</a>
        </langF1>
        <specialty>
            <a title="Neurology" href="neu.aspx">Neurology</a>
        </specialty>
    </Physicians>
</root>
```

If I search for `Lab` the result appears because there is the text `lab` in the column.

Comment: You can add AND NOT LIKE '%Neurology%'. (But that may slow down performance...) Or, much better, do a case-sensitive LIKE, using a case sensitive collation.

Comment: It can be many other things beside Urology and Neurology but so far I was able to catch that... I updated my question.

Comment: I wonder why the database does case folding for the `content` column. Normally, `u != U`.

Comment: @jarlh How do I perform a case-sensitive LIKE?

Comment: Some DBMS's have support for regexes which would help you solve this. Which DBMS are you working with? (i.e. MySQL? PostgreSQL? MS SQL Server?)

Comment: `The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

Comment: Full text indexing will break it into words and be more efficient.

Comment: @AaronDigulla - This is collation dependant in SQL Server whether it is case sensitive or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do if you're not into making a CLR proc to use Regexes (SQL Server doesn't have regex capabilities natively)

```
SELECT
    [...]
WHERE
    (content LIKE @strService OR
     content LIKE '%[^a-z]' + @strService + '[^a-z]%' OR
     content LIKE @strService + '[^a-z]%' OR
     content LIKE '%[^a-z]' + @strService)
```

This way you check to see if content is equal to @strService **OR** if the word exists somewhere within content with non-letters around it **OR** if it's at the very beginning or very end of content with a non-letter either following or preceding respectively.

`[^...]` means *"a character that is none of these"*. If there are other characters you don't want to accept before or after the search query, put them in every 4 of the square brackets (**after the `^`!**). For instance `[^a-zA-Z_]`.

Comment: Thank you for the response... but it is not always Neurology or Urology, but it can be 12 other string as well...

Comment: This is what I am using in my Stored Procedure: `(content LIKE '%'+@strService+'%')` where `strService` is the dropdownlist value.

Comment: Yeah gotcha, so then it would be `LIKE '%[^a-z]' + @strService + '%' OR content LIKE @strService + '%'`. You might want to expand it to accept the `@strService` to be the last word or to have a non-character directly following.

Comment: Do I have to also have the `OR` statement than? Can you update the code with what I provided... Thanks :)

Comment: Edited my answer, so now it's checking to see if `content` is equal to `@strService` or if the word exists somewhere within `content` with non-letters around it or if it's at the very beginning or very end of `content` with a non-letter either following or preceding respectively.

Comment: I was way ahead of you... :) and WOW it is working. Thank you so much. +1 (waiting for the time so I can accept :)...)

Comment: Updated, you can use `LIKE` in stead. I'm wondering whether the content of `@strService` could contain `%` or `[`. If so you wanna escape those by puting `[]` around them. You can do this with a simple `REPLACE()`.

Comment: @strService is always either text or MAYBE a `-` in between two connected text. The edited code should be fine I am guessing...?

Comment: Awesome. You saved me from creating a CLR and doing another SP which would do the conversion slowing down the process. Thanks so much!

Comment: Should I also use `A-Z`? or `a-z` is sufficient enough?

Comment: I came across something, If I search for `Lab` it gives me other results. How do I set it so it doesn't? I updated my question to show you the issue, maybe I have to exclude the `_`?

Comment: Depending on your collation (`_cs` vs. `_ci`) you might want to do `[^a-zA-Z]`. I don't fully understand what result you got that you don't want when searching `Lab`, does it not contain the word lab in any way shape or form?

Comment: one of the line for `content` is `<img src="phys_lab coat_gradation2.jpg?n=7529" />` and that is showing up in the result because `lab` appeared in the column. I updated my question for a better example :)

Comment: Updated the answer with a way to also not accept a `_` before or after the search term.

Answer (score 1):

Databases are notoriously bad at semantics (i.e. they don't understand the concept of neurology or urology - everything is just a string of characters).

The best solution would be to create a table which defines the terms (two columns, PK and the name of the term).

The query is then a join:

```
join table1.term_id = terms.term_id and terms.term = 'Urology'
```

That way, you can avoid the `LIKE` and search for specific results.

If you can't do this, then SQL is probably the wrong tool. Use `LIKE` to get a set of results which match and then, in an imperative programming language, clean those results from unwanted ones.

Comment: Upvoted althought I don't understand why SQL is not "a real programming language". Maybe you wanted to say "in an imperative programming language" ;)

Comment: This is what I am using in my Stored Procedure: `(content LIKE '%'+@strService+'%')` where `strService` is the dropdownlist value.

Comment: Why do you use `LIKE` at all?

Comment: I wish i can use `=` but this is what I get when I use `=`, `The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

Comment: Ah. Try to cast `ntext` to `varchar`.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, your options are to either:

1. Create a function that processes a string and finds a whole match inside it
2. Create a CLR extension that allows you to call .NET code and leverage the REGEX capabilities of .NET

Aaron's suggestion is a good one **IF** you can know up front all the terms that could be used for searching. The problem I could see is if someone searches for a specific word combination.

Comment: This is what I am using in my Stored Procedure: `(content LIKE '%'+@strService+'%')` where `strService` is the dropdownlist value.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your content, can you not leverage the fact that there are quotes in the string you're searching for?

SELECT
[...]
WHERE
(content LIKE '%""Urology""%')